# Fortran graphical user interface

Tags: python, c++, qt, user-interface, fortran

Here is my problem setup. I have Fortran 95 program for numerical analysis. It is highly optimized and parallelized via MPI to perform cluster computing. But as program grows it becomes very difficult to maintain. So I decided to divide program into two parts: GUI and computing module. As I intend to use computing module on clusters it is preferable to retain computing module as a program rather than library. Cross-platform GUI should take computational problem setup parameters and produce set of files which later will be read by computational module. So the questions are: what programming language is the best suited for such GUI development(C++ Qt, python TkInter ?) (I'm not very familiar with other languages except Fortran so language complexity may be cruicial, but I can learn language if it would be beneficial in my case), and what is the best way to establish interconnection between GUI and Fortran computational module (maybe there is some common data format for this, like css, with Fortran parser)? Any recommendations and comments are appreciated. Thank you in advance !

Comment: Sorry, vtc as too broad. You can use any general purpose language, what you like is something you have to find out for yourself.

Comment: But as you're realized just now that separating GUI and logic helps, maybe you should start learning with some language-independent program design stuff, patterns, best practices etc.etc. Otherwise, the only thing you get is more instead of less difficult maintainance.

Comment: You can use the ZeroMQ library to send messages between your Fortran program and your GUI which would be written in some other language. See these links: 1) http://zeromq.org/  2) https://github.com/scemama/f77_zmq   The fortran binding works with version 4.0.6. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. Very helpful. Sorry if my question is not appropriate, but I'm specialising more in natural sciences and sometimes I just need an advice from professional in software development. deviantfan, I'm learning now OOP and patterns and their implementation in Fortran. But what I've experienced recently is that many clusters are still working with older versions of fortran compilers and many features of 2003 and 2008 Fortran standarts are not available. This means that computing module should be as simple as it could be, with mininmum OOP usage.

Comment: Anthony Scemama, thank you for a tip ! As I understand zeroMQ provides some capabilities for message transfer between programs via network. It seems a bit hard and overdo for me to connect GUI with computational module on remote cluster. But it can be a question for the further extension of the software package, and maybe helpful for task scheduling. For now I'm thinking more on simple file-based intercommunication and this files organisation. Any way thanks again for the advice !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad question and might be closed soon for being opinion-based. But I'll try to offer a bit of advice anyway.

You don't mention whether it's feasible to modify the Fortran programme, but let's say it is. I would recommend coming up with some sort of simple, ASCII configuration file format which could be written out by a GUI, and then read back in by the Fortran backend. Doing text stuff in Fortran is a bit of a nightmare, but there are decent C APIs for reading (for example) .ini files, so you could write a routine in C and call it from Fortran via the ISO_C_BINDING module in F2003.

On the GUI side, what would be easiest depends on your environment. When I was doing something very similar, we were using Linux desktops running Gnome so it was natural to write a GUI in GTK. I learnt Python in order to do that, which it turns out is a great first OO language to learn.

Qt is also a great choice, and in general works better than GTK on non-Linux platforms too. It also has good Python bindings from what I understand.

Good luck!

Comment: Doing text stuff in Fortran is a bit of a nightmare - nonsense.

Comment: Tristan, many thanks for your advices ! Vladimir, thanks for your comment ! Now I feel more confident in the chosen direction of development. What you said about possibility of using C for reading *.ini files is very interesting. Actually the last thing that bothers me is how to organise text file written by GUI. At one hand there is no need to develop "bicycles" and on the other hand inventing easy and functional file organisation and I/O routines looks very painful. That's why I've looked into css but I'm in doubt whether it is what I actually need.